# Convert Libre/OpenOffice-Writer document with Libre/OpenOffice-Math to MSWord with Microsoft Equation 3.0

Tags: microsoft-word, libreoffice-writer, openoffice-writer, libreoffice-math

How can I convert Libre/OpenOffice-Writer document with Libre/OpenOffice-Math formulas to MSWord with Microsoft Equation 3.0 formulas? Russian letters changed to '?'.